# Encipher Function Error, Possibly in then Statement, Fixing Code

Tags: haskell

I'm back with another question. I will use my logic and understanding to go through the code, and if it's possible, can you see where my logic is at fault? I ask that because I get an error after running this code which pinpoints the error at the then statement.

I have this code:

```
    encipher :: Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
    encipher _ _ [] = []
    encipher xs ys (z:zs) = if f == []
                    then z:encipher xs ys zs
                    else snd (head f) : (encipher xs ys zs)
        where t = zip xs ys
        f = filter ((== z) . fst) t
```

**Output: [encipher ['A'..'Z'] ['a'..'z'] "THIS" == "this"], where xs = ['A'..'Z'], ys = ['a'..'z'], z = "THIS"**

```
    t = zip xs ys
```

results in [('A','a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')......................('Y', 'y'), ('Z', 'z')]

When I asked my previous question here, I had no understanding of what the last line did but thanks to help from people, I know what it does now(Thank you Guys!). Here is my understanding:

```
    f = filter ((== z) . fst) t
```

First f value we get is

```
    [('T','t')]
```

Obviously,

```
    f /= []
```

and as a result, we go to the else statement where this happens:

```
    't' : encipher xs ys "HIS"
```

Fast forward some of the recursion here, and we will arrive to this point:

```
    'this' : encipher xs ys ""
```

After arriving to this point, "THIS" has been fully processed, giving us "", which will lead to

```
    f = []
```

Now, since f is an empty list, it will go to the then statement and this is where I think my problem lies and the compiler seems to think that as well. Relevant error from compiler:

```
       |
    85 |                         then z:encipher xs ys zs
       |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My question is, what is the code for the then statement such that I get the desired output?
Thanks StackOverflow Community!
Shreeman

Comment: It is useful to think about types. What is the expected result type? Your `then` branch must have that type. If so, what type should `z` have? (Further, you did not post the error message, only the problematic line.) After some thought, you should realize that your type signature promises too much, and must be changed so that it is slightly less general.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly homework, so I'm not going to give the solution away. However, I will give you a gigantic hint that will make the problem (and hopefully the solution) obvious: `encipher ['0', '1'] [False, True] "asdf"` is valid based on your type signature for `encipher`, but obviously can't do anything sensible.

Comment: `encipher ['a', 'd'] [False, True] "asdf"` is a better example, IMO.